# why magmi runs slow sometimes?

Tags: magento-1.7, magmi

**Hey,**

**i just had small doubts regarding Magmi...**

**A)** In my feed file, I newly added 1 column 'small_image', may I know how can i get it values automatically from 'thumbnail' column? Any plugin?

**B)** Why Magmi would be slow sometimes.? I sometimes feel it would be damn fast, sometimes, it adds 2 products in each second.. Any idea on this?  I have 1000's of products, i thought magmi works very fast but unfortunately magmi goes slow sometimes.. Any solution on this would be appreciated

**Please kindly clear above**

**EDITED:**

when I unchecked "Image Attributes Processor" and clicked 'import' button, products added instantly but without images..

when I check 'image atributes processor', magmi taking lot time.. its ading like 2 products per second.. so, how can i make 'image attributes processor' work fast?

**BTW, I use remote images..**

Comment: Sounds like its taking a long time for Magmi to download the remote images. Not really Magmi's fault. The connection between Magmi and the remote server is slow, and/or the images you're trying to download are very large.

Comment: As andyjv has mentioned, this is highly likely due to your remote images. Even if the images are small and your remote server is fast, remote access/downloading images has a lot of overhead.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party extension.

Answer (score 2):

A) You always need to use the column headers image, small_image and thumbnail when using Magmi to upload, and then each label too, so image_label, small_image_label, and thumbnail_label

In relation to images, you may also want to include: position and media_sort_order, with the values for each being 1 if only 1 image is to be uploaded for each product.

B) For remote images, simply enter in your .csv file as:

http://www.domain.com/ImageFolder/ImageName.jpg

Or whatever the url may be.

Can you post a link to 1 of the remote images you are trying to import? As the above answer details it sounds like it is due to the image size or connection to the remote host of the images. Magmi should be able to rip through 1000 products import with remote images in under a minute.